# undefined data result ajax symfony

Tags: php, ajax, symfony, controller, symfony4

ajax displayed for me undefined when I searched a product

```
 /**
 * @Route("/searchProduit ", name="searchProduit")
 */
public function searchProduit(Request $request,NormalizerInterface $Normalizer)
{
    $repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Produit::class);
    $requestString=$request->get('searchValue');
    $products = $repository->findProduitByName($requestString);
    $jsonContent = $Normalizer->normalize($products, 'json',['groups'=>'products']);
    $retour = json_encode($jsonContent);
    return new Response($retour);
}
```

Comment: `return new JsonResponse($products)` That way it encodes the response for you. Other than that `undefined` wouldn't be from Symfony. That sounds more like Javascript, so what is calling the `/searchProduit` in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

first check, if your `$products` returns anything by e.g. dumping it: `dump($products);`

if yes, try to return a `JsonResponse`

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;


// encode your $products on the fly
$response = new JsonResponse($products);

// if the data to send is already encoded in JSON
$response = JsonResponse::fromJsonString('$jsonContent');
```